# How does one pass positional arguments to mine function aliases?

Tags: salt-stack

Using salt 2014.7.0, I can add the following to a minion configuration:

```
mine_functions:
  cmd.run: [echo hello]
```

And then, on the salt master, I can see my 'test' minion retrieving "hello" from the mine:

```
salt 'test' mine.update
salt 'test' mine.get 'test' cmd.run
test:
    ----------
    test:
        hello
```

This all works perfectly well. However, I would like to use a [mine function alias](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/#mine-functions-aliases) instead of the cmd.run handle. The documentation is not clear on how to do this, and nothing I've tried so far will work. The following attempts have failed:

Passing the arguments through in the mine_function:

```
mine_functions:
  say_hello:
    mine_function: 
      cmd.run: [echo hello]
```

Passing the arguments through as the "name" field:

```
mine_functions:
  say_hello:
    mine_function: cmd.run 
    name: echo hello
```

Passing the argments through as an "args" list:

```
mine_functions:
  say_hello:
    mine_function: cmd.run 
    args: [echo hello]
```

But none of these result in the desired outcome, accessing "hello" through the say_hello alias, i.e.:

```
salt 'test' mine.update
salt 'test' mine.get 'test' say_hello
test:
    ----------
    test:
        hello
```

What is the correct way to pass arguments to mine functions when using mine function aliases?

Answer (score 5):

Found a workable solution!

The trick is to use a list as the value for the mine function alias, with the mine_function key as the first value, like so:

```
mine_functions:
  say_hello:
    - mine_function: cmd.run 
    - echo hello
```

This results in the desired output:

```
salt 'test' mine.update
salt 'test' mine.get 'test' say_hello
test:
    ----------
    test:
        hello
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual solution to this is:

```
mine_functions:
  say_hello:
    - mine_function: cmd.run
    - cmd: echo test
```

The key is specifying `cmd: echo test` rather than `name: echo test`.

Here's why:
`mine_functions` execute salt modules, not salt states (per [this documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/#mine-functions)). This is the same as what happens when you run `salt <target> <module>.<method> [args]` on the command-line. Notably, command modules don't necessarily follow the state convention of having `name` as the first parameter.

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run) for the `salt.modules.cmdmod` module (which is used by referencing `cmd.run`, not `cmdmod.run`, for some reason), you'll note that its first parameter is named `cmd` rather than `name`. Using that as the key instead does what you need it to do.